# .Net Framework: API return 500 with large data, works fine with small set of data

Tags: asp.net, .net

Here is my web.config file,

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.1"  maxRequestLength="2147483"  executionTimeout="3600" requestValidationMode="2.0" requestPathInvalidCharacters=""/>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483648" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried putting a break point in your controller ?

Comment: Yes but it breaks before reaching the controller

Comment: So the "large data" is data that you're sending to the controller ?    Maybe you could give us a bit ore information.  What does your request look like ?  What does the the controller's action method expect as parameters ?

Comment: Please provide more information so we can help you out.

Comment: @Mark -  The request looks like [{key1: val1, key2: val2}, ....].Its an array of objects, the object has 2 keys.

Comment: public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Put([FromBody] IEnumerable<MyModel> data)
This is the signature of the controller